# Is there a script for downloading videos from YouTube utilising only Wget or curl on iPhone?

Tags: ios, bash, jailbreak

I'm looking for a script that **does not** utilise [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) and instead [Wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or [curl](https://curl.haxx.se) (coupled with things like sed and other base UNIX utilities that I wouldn't need to install, like no perl).

I'm asking for such a hassle of a job, as my iPhone running iOS 9 can't run utilities like Python or youtube-dl because of architecture issues.

Comment: Are you sure you are installing python from the right source? Unless you're on iOS 11, device architecture shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not, because YouTube is desperate to prevent people from downloading their videos, and if it was that easy, too many people would do it.

`youtube-dl` has to be regularly updated to deal with the changes that YouTube and other sites implement to keep people from downloading videos.